# CKeditor file upload wrong upload

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor on my page but I have a problem with the image upload. I am trying to use the image upload from [this](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/uploadimage) site. But I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZntj.png) as file uploader and not the other one.

The code I have with that is:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';
    config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'insert', items: ['Smiley'] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline' ] },
        { name: 'links', items: [ 'Image' ]  }          
    ];

    config.autoParagraph = false;
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.fullPage = false;    
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(*)[*]{*};span(*)[*]{*};div(*)[*]{*};li(*)[*]{*};ul(*)[*]{*}';

    config.extraPlugins = 'youtube,ckawesome';
    config.fontawesomePath = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';

    config.contentsCss = ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css','https://app.gratiswebshopbeginnen.nl/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'];

    // Se the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    // Make dialogs simpler.
    //config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

The script in the php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
            <script>CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = false; CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false;</script>
            <script>CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;</script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
            {
                customConfig: '/assets/plugins/ckeditor/config.js',
                filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/assets/plugins/ckeditor/plugins/browser/browse.php',
                enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the image you attached, it looks like you got the correct plugin for CKEditor. The only difference is the language, and your picture has more "visible" tabs because some tabs only become available once specific settings are set up in the ckeditor/config.js file. See this screenshot from the UploadImage plugin demo page:

[image]

So, could you be more specific about what is your question or problem?

Answer (score 0):

use the plugin from my github repository [working ckeditor / custom plugin](https://github.com/Anjani001/ckeditor-with-custom-image-upload)